# how to add multiple markers on the google map just by url?

Tags: blackberry-10

I have an android application, I want to convert it to blackberry 10 , the google map  is needed in the app,but the blackberry 10 do not support `GoogleMap`, the blackberry developer web site supply a way to replace it.The sample as below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/?ll=36.97,
                  -122&lci=bike&z=13&t=p");
  }
```

I cannot really understand it,I do not know how to add multiple markers on the `GoogleMap` via url? who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me the map was shown in a webview.